# Conditional generic types in typescript

Tags: typescript

Imagine you have a Foo interface that receives a generic type T like

```
interface Foo<T> {
  ...
  bar: T;
}
```

now you want the T type to be optional, so you set an default value

```
interface Foo<T = undefined> {
  ...
  bar: T;
}
```

but 'bar' is still required.

How do I get 'bar' to be required (not undefined) when type T is set, and remove it (or set it as not required) when Type T is not set?

I've tried something like the lines bellow, but 'bar' is still required. I could add a question mark to the 'bar' property but then 'bar' will not be required when T is set.

```
interface Foo<T = undefined> {
  ...
  bar: T extends undefined ? never : T;
}
```

Any idea if this is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends why you need this, the base and derived interface solution is pretty good for most situations (presented in another answer here).

You can't use a conditional type to make a field optional. But you can use an intersection type instead:

```
type Foo<T = undefined> = {
  otherFields: string
} & ([T] extends [undefined] ? {} : {
  bar: T
})

let x: Foo<undefined> = {
  otherFields: ""
}

let x2: Foo<string> = {
  otherFields: "",
  bar: ""
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFSgXigVwHYBMIBmAlthLgHzpQDeAsAFBRRzAAWEATjERADa4BnAFxQBwDiQDmDAL5QAZFAAUAbWQBdKBAAewCHgFQVOfMVK5NAfhpyRdRlABGAQw4jksgJQMGvCMChtEXgkE0ISMkoMeyYWdi4efmEoACIU2R96PwDtACZghEQxCWxJKJoGWLZObj5BETSAGkqnVwb0+hkgA)

Comment: Converting the interface to a type an then using the intersections seams to do the trick! Thanks! I was trying to avoid the derived solution interface because with multiple generic types I would end up with too many interfaces for the same porpoise

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
type Foo<T = undefined> = T extends undefined ? {} : {
   bar: T
}

const foo : Foo = { bar: "hello" }
const bar: Foo<string> = { bar: "hello" }
const foobar : Foo = {}
```

Comment: Don't know if I explained well, but in that case I'll still receive the error Property 'bar' is missing in type '{ ... }' but required in type 'Foo<any>'.ts(2741)

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. You don't want it required when T is not set?

Comment: exactly, and only when T is not set

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: So close, few minutes after Titian answer :) Unfortunately can not mark the two as accepted. Will upvote since is correct as well

Answer (score 1):

You can model it with two interfaces

```
interface FooBase {
  // all expext bar 
}

interface Foo<T> extends FooBase {
  bar: T
}
```

this way the interface `FooBase` contains every thing that that is always requiered and `Foo` only conatins `bar` but also enforces every thing that is declared by `FooBase`.

Comment: That's a solution but not really the answer. I'm trying to avoid that to no not ending up with a naming nightmare, when I'll have multiple names for the 'same' interface

Comment: But it is literally not the same interface, the purpose of an interface is to grantee the presence of fileds, properties and methods. And an interface where _conditionally_ a filed is missing produces completely different types.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Probably should have added more context to the question. I'll not use that interfaces directly, the goal here is then to create multiple types based on that generic interfaces. In this case they will be used in redux actions where I'll have multiple types that only vary in a string literal and have a payload property or not. With the Titian and Todd solutions I will be able to enforce the presence of a property only by it's interface declaration instead of having to combine the declaration with the interface name. But for simpler cases your answer should be the one to go to